# Display UL elements in more columns

Tags: html, css, challenge-response

Is it possible somehow achieve to display LI tags from one UL in multiple columns?

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

I now I can get it with nested ul tags, but if is it possible it would be great! Even when some li tags would be used to separate columns, but I don't know how to style it.

Comment: What is the data you are representing?  In this case it may make more sense to use a table

Comment: Data represents some solid list of items in entity, but just nedd to show it in more columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a wrapper around your UL and use the new CSS3 "columns":

```
<div class="columns">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And then style with CSS:

```
.columns {
 -moz-column-count: 3;
 -moz-column-gap: 1em;
 -webkit-column-count: 3;
 -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
}
```

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NEHwE/

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have them floating left, and clearing them every n items. This would simulate a fixed amount of columns, and work in IE9+ and all the other browsers

```
li{
    float: left;
}

li:nth-child(4n+1){ /*replace 4 with the number of columns*/
    clear: left;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CdVAf/)

Answer (score 0):

The old fashion way.

the css style:

```
.ul li { float: left; margin-right: 20px; }
```

and the implementation:

```
<div class="ul">
    <ul>
        <li>Col 1</li>
        <li>Col 2</li>
        <li>Col 3</li>
        <li>Col 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```